# Why is the root always null in this method insert method for binary tree

Tags: java, recursion, binary-search-tree

Iam trying to implement a recursive insert node method for BST class

```
 public void insertNode(Node r, Node n)
{
    if(r == null)
    {
        System.out.println("r=n"+ n.data);
        r = n;
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("r=! null finding place in tree for "+ n.data);
        if(n.data <= r.data)
        {
            if(r.left == null)
                r.left = n;
            else
                insertNode(r.left, n);
        }
        else
        {
            if(r.right == null)
                r.right = n;
            else
                insertNode(r.right, n);
        }
    }
}
```

Im trying to invoke this method like so:

```
  int[] arrTree = {34, 2, 56, 12, 44, 39, 56, 1};
    BT t = new BT();
    for (int i = 0; i < arrTree.length; i++)
    {
        //System.out.println("Tree Root = "+ t.getRoot());
        BT.Node n =  t.new Node(arrTree[i]);
        t.insertNode(t.root, n);
    }
```

But Im always getting this output:

```
 r=n34
 r=n2
 r=n56
 r=n12
 r=n44
 r=n39
 r=n56
 r=n1
```

Node is an inner class of BT.

I cannot figure it out after hours of running and trying different things what Im doing wrong.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Java "pass-by-reference" or "pass-by-value"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the code you've shown, my money's on the error being here:

```
public void insertNode(Node r, Node n)
{
    if(r == null)
    {
        System.out.println("r=n"+ n.data);
        r = n; //you overwrite the value of r but never use it
    }
```

`Node r` is actually a separate reference to whatever `t.root` refers to, so replacing `r` with another value won't change whatever `t.root` refers to outside the method. You can modify the referenced data inside a method, but not the reference itself.

Answer (score 1):

Java is pass-by value language. In case of objects you pass the value of the reference, thus, creating *new reference*.

```
public void insertNode(Node r, Node n) {
    if(r == null) {
        r = n;
    }
```

Here you substitute the *new reference* to the root with the other reference; original reference to root (`t.root`) left unchanged.

To fix this issue you can get rid of the first parameter in the `insertNode()` method - the tree's root is the part of its implementation, so the tree already knows the reference to its root. Change all `r`s inside `insertNode()` to `this.root`.

Comment: Hi Thanks. But how can I use recursive method if I take away the r?

Comment: The wording on this is slightly wrong.  You pass the value of the reference, but the value of the reference doesn't permit you to reassign it.  You don't create a new reference at all.

Comment: @Makoto What would you say gets reassigned then? Because you are reassigning something.

Answer (score 0):

When you set r within the method, it does not affect the node that you pass in.  So t.root is never set.